# Cómo hago para activar una imágen al pasar el ratón por encima del botón que la activa

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que una imágen se active al pasar el ratón por encima del botón que la activa, pero no he logrado cómo hacerlo... antes este codigo que he usado si me funcionaba pero ahora no funciona de ninguna manera, no sé que hacer.

```css
.img-mouse{
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.img-a-mostrar{
    display: none;
}
/* Aquí está la magia que no me funciona*/
.img-mouse:hover + .img-a-mostrar {
    display: block !important; /* activamos la imágen y hasta le ruego con un !important */
}
```

```html
<a class='img-mouse'>pasa el ratón y mira la imagén</a>  
<!-- ya he probado con <button> pero tampoco -->

<img class='img-a-mostrar' src='http://placehold.jp/150x150.png'/>
```

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Comment: Yo veo que si funciona, quizás el problema sea otro. Intenta desde un navegador diferente o en una pestaña de incógnito.

Comment: Yo también puedo ver como aparece la imagen sin problemas. Tal y como te indica @JessHilario, prueba con otro navegador o borrando la caché del navegador que estés usando. Hay muchas veces que la caché puede jugar malas pasadas. Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que verifiques que el fichero de CSS está bien enlazado a tu página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo tiene que crear una clase

```
    .img-a-mostrar{
      display: none;
}
    .img-a-mostar:hover{
      background: #ff0000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: block;
}
```

Comment: Y cómo se supone que se activará la imágen sin el botón? si está desactivada